# Connect remotely to an APIPA assigned host

Tags: windows, networking, ip, hyper-v-server-2012

I had the unfortunate (and not correctly planned) event of having one of my remote Hyper-V hosts assigned an APIPA address hence i cannot connect by any means on it.

Funny thing is, i can RDP to the VM that runs atop of the host.

I can also RDP to the Hyper-V DR host which continues to replicate with the primary Hyper-V host using the APIPA address.

I was able to see that it is using an APIPA address using Resource Manager, on the Network tab.

The host isn't pingable either using it's internal IP or it's hostname and of course neither from APIPA (not sure if that's pingable anyway).

Both Hyper-V hosts are running Windows 2012 R2 Standard and the VM that lies atop of the primary host is Windows 2011 SBS.

As i don't have the chance to physically access the server (it is located in another continent), is there any way that i can access it?

Comment: Try configuring a virtual IP (in the APIPA range) on another (and maybe less important) server that is on the same physical subnet as the problematic server, and see if you can reach it.

Comment: If the DR host can still see the host in question, can't you RDP from the DR host to it?  Are you using any OOB iLo or DRAC on the affected machine?

Comment: @EliadTech Can you post your comment as an answer in order to accept it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Configure a virtual IP](http://www.aptare.com/online_documentation/9.2/System%20Administrator%27s%20Guide/$H_85.html) (in the APIPA range) on another (and maybe less important) server that is on the same physical subnet as the problematic server, and then you'll be able to connect.